# Currency not change in home page, the rest of website works fine

Tags: full-page-cache, currency, ee-1.14.3.0

My store handle many currencies, and if I change the currency, it works in  all pages, but in homepage.

I'm using FPC, but in all pages, currency block is refreshed, but in homepage don't.

### I have tried many ways to exclude the blocks from cache, but it seems like the whole homepage is cached, or something like that. so, have you any idea what can I do ?

I see, in chrome the currency not switch in home page. but in firefox and safari the currency switch fine